# The disparity in the portrayal of exorcisms between the Old and New Testaments. Why is there such an imbalance?

Tags: exorcism

In the Old Testament, there are no specific accounts of exorcisms as we know them from the New Testament. The Old Testament contains several references to evil spirits and demons, but the texts focus more on describing the negative influence of these beings rather than detailing rituals of exorcism to expel them.

In the New Testament, however, exorcisms are more frequent and described in detail. The Gospels, in particular, report several occasions where Jesus expels demons from possessed individuals. Some examples include the exorcism of the Gerasene demoniac (Mark 5:1-20), the healing of the demon-possessed boy (Mark 9:14-29), and the liberation of a woman possessed (Luke 13:10-17). Additionally, Jesus' disciples also perform exorcisms in His name.

My question is about the disparity in the portrayal of exorcisms between the Old and New Testaments. Why is there such an imbalance?

Comment: Due to the presence of Jesus, Satan drew near to tempt him in the wilderness. Thereafter, demonic spirits were active in the vicinity. This is hardly surprising, that enemy forces should gather around a target. This giving an opportunity for Jesus to deliver many from their power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The imbalance is due to the evolution of Jewish demonology in the period between the Babylonian Exile and the first century c.e. In addition, Old Testament monotheism did not describe evil spirits as acting independent of God.  They were thought of as "gods" (1 Sam. 28:13) so publishing stories about them might give credence to the existence of "other gods."

However, there is indeed an account of exorcism in the Hebrew Bible, although it may be argued that it is a case of spiritual influence rather than possession per se:

1 Samuel 16:23

> Whenever the spirit from God came upon Saul, David would take the harp
> and play, and Saul would be relieved and feel better, for the evil
> spirit would leave him.

It is significant in this context that every time "evil spirit" or "lying spirit" appears in the OT (Judges 9:23, 1 Samuel 16:14, 2 Chronicles 18:22), it is a spirit sent by God. The authors' commitment to monotheism was so absolute that it would not admit the independent agency of evil spirits. Even Satan is an agent of God (Job 1-2).

During the Babylonian Exile and the period of Persian rule, Jews became familiar with Mesopotamian traditions regarding the influence of evil spirits:

> In ancient Mesopotamia, it was believed that all forms of sickness
> came from powerful spirits entering a person’s body and attaching to a
> person.  Assyrian tablets make reference to the use of incantations
> and prayers to the gods, as well as direct challenges to demons, which
> were believed to inflict every type of disease, both physical and
> psychological. Ancient Babylonian priests performed rituals by
> destroying a clay or wax image of a demon. Accounts from ancient Persia, dating back to around 600 BC, offer evidence of exorcism using prayer, ritual, and holy water by the religious leader Zoroaster, who was considered the first magician, and who founded the religion Zoroastrianism. -- [source](https://www.ancient-origins.net/news-mysterious-phenomena-unexplained-phenomena/ancient-practice-exorcism-rise-again-001211)

Zoroastrianism - a religion which emphasizes the struggle between [two Cosmic principalities](https://www.pbs.org/newshour/arts/ancient-but-small-in-number-zoroastrians-confront-depletion-of-their-faith#:%7E:text=At%20its%20core%2C%20Zoroastrianism%20emphasizes,words%20and%20do%20good%20deeds) - also exposed Judaism to the possibility that evil entities acted independent of God's sovereignty. Jewish accounts of exorcisms begin to appear in the intertestamental literature. For example in the Book of Tobit, the exorcism of a woman possessed by an evil spirit is central to the story's plot:

Tobit 8

> 2 Tobiah, mindful of Raphael’s instructions, took the fish’s liver and heart from the bag where he had them, and put them on the embers intended for incense. 3 The odor of the fish repulsed the demon, and it fled to the upper regions of Egypt; Raphael went in pursuit of it and there bound it hand and foot.

The [Testament of Solomon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testament_of_Solomon) provides an example of capturing an evil spirit, though not exorcizing them per se:

> 119. I called my servant and said to him: "Order thy camel
>      and take for thyself a leather flask, and take also this seal. And go
>      away into Arabia to the place in which the evil spirit blows; and
>      there take the flask, and the signet-ring in front of the mouth of the
>      flask, and (hold them) towards the blast of the spirit. And when the
>      flask is blown out, thou wilt understand that the demon is (in it).

Writings such as the Book of Enoch helped intensify awareness of the influence of evil spirits. In addition Greek and other pagan traditions interacted increasingly with Jewish culture as large numbers of Jews lived abroad - and both [Greek and Roman traditions](http://www.missiology.org/folkreligion/Howellarticle.pdf) of exorcism moved to the Jewish lands such as the Galilee and neighboring provinces.

**Conclusion**: the comparatively frequent depictions of exorcisms in the NT compared to the OT is due to the fact Jews remained isolated from neighboring cultures until the time of the Babylonian exile. In addition, the Hebrew Bible would naturally downplay the influence of evil spirits as it adhered to an absolute monotheism in which evil entities did not operate independently from God.

Comment: "isolated from neighboring cultures" and yet the Old Testament the influence of outside cultures is mentioned. In Exodus they lived in Egypt. In 1 Samuel 8:6 Israel demands a king "like all the nations". Prophets often talked about God's people being influenced by outside cultures to worship other gods.

Comment: The Israelites certainly knew about other nations. But with the exception of the period in Egypt, which was in the distant past and prior to the giving of the Law,  it was only during and after the Babylonian exile that they lived in these lands. But it is possible that Canaanite traditions of exorcism existed. These are not evident in the sources as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the presence of Jesus, Satan drew near to tempt him in the wilderness. Thereafter, demonic spirits were active in the vicinity.

This is hardly surprising, that enemy forces should gather around a target.

This giving an opportunity for Jesus to deliver many from their power.

Comment: Are you saying that demon possession is a result of Jesus presence on earth? If so is there scripture that says this?

Comment: @DavidD, good point!

Comment: @DavidD Link Jesus' words in Luke 10:18 with Revelation 12:4-9 & 13 to grasp how Satan and his demons were cast down to the earth (in relation to the man-child being born to God;s woman, i.e. Jesus). Satan fell from heaven like lightning, Jesus observed, at the casting out of demons from people, on earth, when his disciples used his name  to do that. Yes, from the time of Christ, those evil ones are now confined to earth, raging. They are invisible to humans, but demonic activity is seen with spiritual 'eyes' of discernment.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, demons were free to roam all over the place in heaven, as was Satan (see Job chapter 2). The universe was open to them (see Daniel chapter 9 from verse 20 through to chapter 10 verse 21). They were busy 'working on' the nations surrounding Israel, to incite them to lewd demonic practices of idol worship. And when Israel allowed itself to be 'contaminated' by such idolatry, the demons just had to laugh up their sleeve (spiritually speaking) to see Israel fall.

Ah, but come the start of Jesus' ministry on earth, a drastic reversal took place with regard to Satan and his demons! Jesus saw with his spiritual eyes of discernment the significance of his disciples casting out demons from people, using the authority of Jesus' mighty name:

> "And the seventy returned again with joy, saying, Lord, even the
> devils are subject to us through thy name. And he said unto them, I
> saw Satan as lightning fall from heaven... Notwithstanding in this
> rejoice not, that the spirits are subject unto you; but rather
> rejoice, because your names are written in heaven. Luke 10:17-20 K.J.

More is said about such unseen spiritual events, of Satan and his hordes being defeated, in Colossians 2:15. Paul says that Christ has triumphed over "principalities and powers". He began to do that at the very start of his ministry (defeating Satan with his temptations), continuing through with his authority over demons that had to do what he commanded them, and Christ's disciples also exercising such authority in his name.

Then in Revelation 12:4-9 and verse 13 John had received a vision of the 'birth' of Christ and the resulting war in heaven, where Satan and his demon followers were cast down to earth, confined there. Of course, Satan is raging about that, but he and his demons are powerless to do more than deceive the nations, and wreck their havoc on the earth, hence,

> "Woe to the inhabiters of the earth and of the sea! for the devil is
> come down unto you, having great wrath, because he knoweth that he
> hath but a short time." Revelation 12:12 K.J.

Those who belong to the spiritual Church of Christ know the truth of this, seeing with their spiritual 'eyes' of understanding the increasingly vicious and deadly attacks against "the remnant of her seed", to this very day (12:17). But most people laugh at the very idea of invisible demonic forces, which continue to use as their strongest weapon, blinding peoples' minds to the reality of their existence.

**Summary:** The 'imbalance' is due to the sudden casting down of those evil ones to earth at the time of Christ. Now they are confined to this realm of activity, they focus on trying to destroy "the remnant of" the woman's "seed" - the Church of Christ. But it's not about exorcisms - it's about "seeing" increasingly devilish activity all over the earth in the build-up to Christ's return, when those evil ones will forever be tormented in the sulphuric lake of fire - Revelation 19:20 & 20:8-15.

Comment: How can there be a war in heaven with satan when he is "confined to this realm of activity"?

Comment: @DavidD  Obviously, the war in heaven lead to his being cast down to earth. And Jesus saw Satan fall, like lightning. This, of course, means that Michael (the angel who fought against Satan and his hosts in heaven) could not be Jesus Christ, so some who think that might try chipping in now with their objections to that, which will takes things off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Jesus performed exorcisms to demonstrate his authority and power to forgive sin. In Matthew 9:6, He said, ***"But I want you to know that the Son of Man has authority on earth to forgive sins.”*** Exorcism doesn't exist in the Old Testaments because no one on earth had this authority.

In Matthew 12:43-45 and Luke 11:24-26 NIV, Jesus used a metaphor to describe the danger of returning to sin after being freed from it. He said,

> 43 “When an impure spirit comes out of a person, it goes through arid places seeking rest and does not find it. 44 Then it says, ‘I will return to the house I left.’ When it arrives, it finds the house unoccupied, swept clean and put in order. 45 Then it goes and takes with it seven other spirits more wicked than itself, and they go in and live there. And the final condition of that person is worse than the first. That is how it will be with this wicked generation.”

Comment: @vincncentwong, you said: "” Exorcism doesn't exist in the Old Testaments because no one on earth had this authority.".but, were there possed people at the old testament time? no single case of possrssion. this is quite odd.

Comment: @HumbertoJoséBortolossi - your question is about 'exorcism', at act of a person to cast out demons in another person. It should have people possessed by demons in the OT time. But who had the authority to cast them out? If the Lord's spirit cast out demons from a person without an advocate, can we describe it as exorcism?